# Windows iScsi software initiator automatic reconnect

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am using sofware iscsi initiator in windows server 2008 r2 to connect to a san. Everything works fine.

But issue is if at time of boot san is not available it's not adding drives. It stays in reconnecting status when san is available. I have to manually disconnect and connect to get it working.

How can i make it automatically connect when san is available.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `Microsoft iSCSI Initiator Service` is set to `Automatic` start.